# Having trouble with bubble sort C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm having trouble with my bubble sort code. I am trying to sort a vector of strings containing numbers. It seems to work and then  halfway through comparing numbers it starts to compare everything wrong (ex: it thinks that 4 > 35).

I read in the number from a text file while running the .o file

Here is the .txt file

```
6
89
-9
4
718
-60
35
92
1
```

Here it what I have:

```
using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(vector<string>&); //declare sort function                                                                    

int main()
{
  vector<string> v; //Initialize vector                                                                                      
  string s; //Initialize string                                                                                              

  while (cin >> s)
    v.push_back(s);

  bubbleSort(v); //call sort function
}

void bubbleSort(vector<string>& v){

 for(int i = 0; i <= v.size(); i++) //start first loop through vector                                                        
  for(int j = i+1; j < v.size(); j++){ //start second loop through vector 
     if(v[i] > v[j]){ //compare i-th element to i-th+1 (j-th) element
        swap(v[i],v[j]); //swap elements if i-th element is greater than j-th element
 for (int k = 0; k != v.size(); ++k) //loop through vector and print out binomials one per line                             
cout << v[k] << endl;
}
```

And this is what it outputs:

```
-60
-9
1
35
4
6
718
89
92
```

If someone could please tell me where I am going wrong it would be greatly appreciated! I don't understand why it works all the way up until it tries to compare 4 to 35 and then incorrectly compares them and throws everything off.

Comment: "4" is actually bigger than "35". If you want to compare numbers, compare numbers, not strings.

Comment: You can write this for example: `if(atoi(v[i]) > atoi(v[j]))`, i think it should solve the problem.

Comment: Your outer loop will go out of bounds, but the inner loop will make mask the problem.

Comment: It is better to use c++11 `std::stoi` to convert strings to ints.

Comment: @Satus: You are right, but from this code i am unsure if he have C++11. I think an even better solution would be to make the bubblesort on a vector<int> instead of string.

Comment: @Melkon Yes, the right way would be receiving string from input, then converting it to int and adding that int to vector.

Comment: @molbdnilo this will compare `const char*`'s, not `std::string`'s

Comment: @Satus Temporary brain melt.

Comment: @Michael See my answer. I think it's correct according you string vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In string, "4" is actually bigger than "35". If you want to compare as a numbers, you should convert `string to int`. Then you find your desired answer.

You can do that by simply change if condition statement `if( atoi(v[i].c_str()) > atoi(v[j].c_str()) )` in bubblesort function

So, the final code is:

```
void bubbleSort(vector<string>& v)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) //start first loop through vector
        for(int j = i+1; j < v.size(); j++)  //start second loop through vector
        {
            if( atoi(v[i].c_str()) > atoi(v[j].c_str()) )
            {
                swap(v[i],v[j]); //swap elements if i-th element is greater than j-th element

            }
        }
    for (int k = 0; k != v.size(); ++k) //loop through vector and print out binomials one per line
                    cout << v[k] << endl;

}
```

Output:

```
-60
-9
1
4
6
35
89
92
718
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! This was causing me so much confusion but the converting part is very clear to me now.

Comment: Hey again, was wondering if you could help me with sorting decimals. My program thinks -6.19 > -6.09 when sorting. any ideas? Edit: Nevermind, right after posting this I realized it was because of using atoi, now using atof.

Comment: Hey, `atoi & atof` also doing good. If I use `atof`, nothing problem happen. also recognize `-6.09 > -6.19`. My code is here. Take a look. You can me also you code and hope I will be find your problem.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12311828/

Comment: Do you know how to compare one part of a string to another? For example if I'm comparing 16x-89 and 16x+36, 16x+36 should come first because the constant coefficient is greater. Essentially I need to check if 16 == 16 then look at the constant and compare them and swap them if they need to be swapped

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that although 33 is a bigger int then 4, if you compare strings it isn't the case. StrING compare checks the first char against the first char and if there is an equality it moves on to check next char. So if comparing 4 with 33 you get that 33 is lesser because 3 is lesser then 4.

Solution: use atoi to change the string to int and then check who is bigger

Answer (score 0):

Basically what's going wrong is that strings do a lexicographical compare by default.  Easiest fix is just to change your vector-of-strings into a vector-of-int and filling that vector with an int-converted-from-string (assuming that that conversion succeeds).  How to convert a string to an int is something else to search the web or SO for.

Comment: Or, you can just read `int`s and bypass the whole conversion mess.